# finding out absolute path to a file from python

Tags: python, filesystems, io

If I have a file `test.py` that resides in some directory, how can I find out from `test.py` what directory it is in? `os.path.curdir` will give the current directory but not the directory where the file lives. If I invoke `test.py` from some directory `foo`, `os.curdir` will return `foo` but not the path of `test.py`.

thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

the answer is to use:

```
 __file__
```

which returns a relative path.

```
os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

can be used to get the full path.

Answer (score 53):

Here's how to get the directory of the current file:

```
import os
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.

Answer (score 5):

The answers so far have correctly pointed you to `os.path.abspath`, which does exactly the job you requested.  However don't forget that [os.path.normpath](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=normpath#os.path.normpath) and `os.path.realpath` can also be very useful in this kind of tasks (to normalize representation, and remove symbolic links, respectively) in many cases (whether your specific use case falls among these "many" is impossible to tell from the scant info we have, of course;-).

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) has lots of tools for dealing with paths and getting information about paths.

Particularly, you want:

```
os.path.abspath
```