# python location of the running program on windows

Tags: python, command-line, path

I have an python application that need to know in which directory it founded when it run,

how can i know the running application path on windows for example when i change the directory path is changed to the new directory .

is there a way to know where is the python application run withour saving it on the beginning by os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**))

for example the to know where the application runs after os.chdir("c:/")

```
     import os 
     print os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
     os.chdir("c:/")
     print os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding out absolute path to a file from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283306/finding-out-absolute-path-to-a-file-from-python)

Comment: Hi SilentGhost I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

it is contained in the `__file__` variable.

But if you want to know the current working directory then you should use [`os.getcw`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd).

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Program Files\\Python31'
>>> os.chdir(r'C:\\')
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

edit : little late !!! :)
edit2 : in C# u can use the property `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` so using something like this will help http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html