# Python os module open file above current directory with relative path

Tags: python, file-io, cgi, cgi-bin

The documentation for the OS module does not seem to have information about how to open a file that is not in a subdirectory or the current directory that the script is running in without a full path. My directory structure looks like this.

```
/home/matt/project/dir1/cgi-bin/script.py
/home/matt/project/fileIwantToOpen.txt

open("../../fileIwantToOpen.txt","r")
```

Gives a file not found error. But if I start up a python interpreter in the cgi-bin directory and try `open("../../fileIwantToOpen.txt","r")` it works. I don't want to hard code in the full path for obvious portability reasons. Is there a set of methods in the OS module that *CAN* do this?

Comment: Hmm. This could be a permissions error, or the working directory for the CGI might not be the same as your python interpreter. The exact error message might help. Also, in your CGI, try `print os.getcwd()` and see what that says.

Comment: Is your CGI script running in a chroot jail?  If so, then this won't work since you can't escape from the jail.

Comment: @ Adam Rosenfield no. @Jason I literally run the python interpreter in the cgi-bin directory so I don't understand how it would work in that one and not inside the script that is running in the cgi-bin directory.

Comment: The above worked for me in combination with this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/3283336/706798

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The path given to `open` should be relative to the current working directory, the directory from which you run the script. So the above example will only work if you run it from the cgi-bin directory.

A simple solution would be to make your path relative to the script. One possible solution.

```
from os import path

basepath = path.dirname(__file__)
filepath = path.abspath(path.join(basepath, "..", "..", "fileIwantToOpen.txt"))
f = open(filepath, "r")
```

This way you'll get the path of the script you're running (basepath) and join that with the relative path of the file you want to open. `os.path` will take care of the details of joining the two paths.

Comment: this command just gives me ../../fileIwantToOpen.txt as the path and it still can't find it.

Comment: @terminus: `basepath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`, and `os.path.join(basepath, '..', '..', 'fileIwantToOpen.txt')`. I'd also use `__file__` rather than `sys.argv[0]` myself.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, fixed now. The `split` thing seems to be a bad habit of mine.

Comment: I'm still just getting the full path to the current directory with ../../fileIwantToOpen.txt appended to the end of that.

Comment: @terminus: also you shouldn't call a variable `file` (because of `__builtins__.file`). And `import os`, not `import os.path`.

Comment: @Matt: make sure you've got the `os.path.abspath` bit - os.path.join will just join them, abspath sorts out the `..`s. It does work.

Comment: @Matt that's odd since `os.path.abspath` should convert relative paths to absolute.

Comment: Yes I left that part out for some reason. os.path.dirname also worked for me too. It works now!

Answer (score 6):

This should move you into the directory where the script is located, if you are not there already:

```
file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
if file_path != "":
    os.chdir(file_path)
open("../../fileIwantToOpen.txt","r")
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is really outdated, and Python3 has much better file functionality. This is the first Google result when you're looking up how to open a file in a directory above your script. So here's a newer way of doing this.

```
from pathlib import Path

Path(__file__).joinpath(Path("../../fileIwantToOpen.txt")).open(mode='r')
```

Important details:

__file__ is an absolute path to the file that was called.

.joinpath is a Path method that joins two path sections.

The Path object can use relative paths without issues.

Path objects have their own open() method, so you don't need to use open() on them, unless you prefer it for stylistic reasons.