# Finding path for corpus in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, filepath

I am using the Natural Language Toolkit for python to write a program. In it I am trying to load a corpus of my own files. To do that I am using code to the following effect:

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
corpus_root=(insert filepath here)
wordlists=PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
```

Let's say my file is called reader.py and my corpus of files is located in a directory called 'corpus' in the same directory as reader.py. I would like to know a way to generalize finding the filepath above, so that my code could find the path for the 'corpus' directory for any location for anyone using the code. I have tried these posts, but they only allow me to get absolute file paths:
[Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand

1. Your `reader.py` file and `corpus` directory are always in the same directory
2. You're looking for a way to refer to `corpus` from `reader.py` regardless of where you put them in your directory structure

In that case, [the question that you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory) seems to be what you need. Another way of doing it is in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4381638/583834). Using that second option, your code would then be:

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
import os.path
import sys

basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
corpus_root= os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, "corpus"))
wordlists=PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
```

Keep in mind that while an absolute path is created, it is created based on the information obtained in the `basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)` bit above, which yields `reader.py`'s current directory. Have a look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) for some official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\corpora
```

I used Anaconda Platform, with conda environment... my corpora location

Comment: Does this really answer the question?