# Repeating Import Module - Python / Pygame

Tags: python, import, module, pygame

Ive been working on a simple game in Pygame and I am currently at the stage of adding outcomes to events in each level (eg. Death). Currently I have it set to import the same module when enter is pressed, if a death occurs so the level is 'restarted'. The code functions properly for the first 'restart' however if I play through again it does not import the same level for a second time.

Heres the code I have so far:

```
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN and health == 0:
        import PracticeLevel
```

I am quite new to python so I apologise if any mistakes are present, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very odd way to do this, but your problem is that python is 'smart' about importing (it won't import the same module twice). Importing is more for retrieving functions and classes from the module, and shouldn't really be used to just execute a python file like you are doing. The general way of doing something like this would be to create a `run_level(filename)` function which would load the level data and run it, however if you don't want to change your current format, you should just use `execfile("PracticeLevel.py")` instead of the `import` statement.

#### Edit

If you are using Python 3 (in which `execfile` is not a builtin function), you can write

```
 exec(open(filename).read())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I tried the 'execfile' solution you mentioned however I am just met with an error stating it has not been defined :( Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly :) One additional question, if I was to use your suggestion and the PracticeLevel file was located in a subfolder, how would I link the PracticeLevel file back to the MainMenu file which is located in the parent folder? I tried 'exec(open("Alien/Menu.py").read())' However it doesnt see the file, is there a different way to link back to the parent folder? Thank you

Comment: @Oscar To open a file in an above directory, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381569/python-os-module-open-file-above-current-directory-with-relative-path. It can be done, but not simply, which is one of a couple reasons why this method might not be the best to use. What I would suggest is, instead of trying to run `Menu.py` from inside of `PracticeLevel.py` (I'm assuming you want to return to the menu after the level finishes) I would instead load `Menu.py` directly after your `exec(open('Practice..'`. This way it will load as soon as `PracticeLevel.py` finishes running.