# Spyder retrieve script path when script is not executed

Tags: python, directory, path

I have a script `myscript.py` and within it I have some relative import:

```
# here the relative import fails if I didn't launch the application through
# the script itself or if I am not executing the whole script.
prodquery=open('.\ProductionQueries\myquery.sql','r')
myquery=prodquery.read()
prodquery.close()
```

I often have the need to run specific cells of the script and I need to stick to relative imports as I work on different machines.

I found plenty of similar questions but each answer refers to the case of executing the entire script (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137509/3284713) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283336/3284713)).

Is there a way to retrieve the script path and update the current directory accordingly?
I would assume that the information is stored somewhere, since it appears in the editor.
[image: example]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? (or maybe to the right answer if this is already on SO.)